# Can't run Tomcat from Intellij Idea

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

I installed Tomcat using this guide:
https://help.ubuntu.com/13.04/serverguide/tomcat.html

When I successfully run it from the console, but when I try to run it using Intellij Idea error occurs: "Error running Tomcat : Can't find directory '/usr/share/tomcat7/conf'"

Application server configuration in Idea:

```
Tomcat Home: /usr/share/tomcat7
Tomcat Base: /var/lib/tomcat7
```

Comment: Why tomcat home and base are too different folders ? where do you run tomcat from (start.sh) ?

Comment: /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/catalina.sh - running from. Setting up Tomcat base to /usr/share/tomcat7 doesn't help.

Comment: Does a `conf` folder exist under that base ?

Comment: Download and unpack Tomcat 7 `tar.gz` from the official site, point IDEA to it. Ubuntu package will not work because of the different layout.

Comment: Well, after I copied folder conf to /usr/share/tomcat7 new error occured : Error running Tomcat : Error copying configuration files from /var/lib/tomcat7/conf to /home/exceptis/.IntelliJIdea12/system/tomcat/Tomcat__ChatIM/conf : /var/lib/tomcat7/conf/tomcat-users.xml (Permission denied)

Comment: do u need to fix your permissions?

Comment: Well I tried to fix my permission, but it didn't help. I followed CrazyCoder's advice and installed it manually, also this tutorial helped http://diegobenna.blogspot.com/2011/01/install-tomcat-7-in-ubuntu-1010.html. Now it works!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that the layout is as they call "non-standard"

The problem has been marked as solved here: [IntelliJ needs to copy tomcat conf dir to project directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428126/intellij-needs-to-copy-tomcat-conf-directory-to-project-directory/16428760#16428760)

> Note that Tomcat installed using the package manager on some Linux
>   systems has non-standard layout and permissions, and therefore will
>   not work with IDEA.

Comment: By the way, NetBeans automatically configures the layout of your external Tomcat "base" folder to be "standard", so this entire problem is non-existent. Annoying that IntelliJ 2018 still cannot perform this simple chore of configuring the Tomcat base folder.

Answer (score 23):

In my case, creating a soft link and changing the access permission solved the problem

```
    cd /usr/share/tomcat7
    ln -s /etc/tomcat7 conf
    chmod -R 655 /etc/tomcat7/
```

I have replied to the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27342704/732328)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem earlier and followed these steps to get it working:

1. create a new group for tomcat `sudo groupadd tomcat`
2. create a tomcat user and add this user to the tomcat group created earlier
   `sudo useradd -M -s /bin/nologin -g tomcat -d /opt/tomcat tomcat`
3. Update permissions for tomcat on the installation directory (e.g., /opt/tomcat as used above)

````
sudo chgrp -R tomcat /opt/tomcat (this gives tomcat ownership over the directory)
sudo chmod -R g+r conf
sudo chmod g+x conf (this and the one above gives tomcat read/write perm on conf dir)
sudo chown -R tomcat webapps/ work/ temp/ logs/ (makes user, tomcat, owner of the following dirs)
4. Open tomcat installation parent directory, i.e., /opt, as root, right click on the tomcat folder -> properties -> permissions -> folder access, change to create and delete files.```

And Jesus said, "It is finished."
````