# How to run "hello world" JSP page with Tomcat8 in Intellij IDEA 15?

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, permissions

I created webproject template in Intellij IDEA 15 (EE) and tried to run "hello world" application with simple JSP page on installed Tomcat server. But I've got this kind of error:

```
Error running Tomcat 8.0.33: Error copying configuration files from /opt/tomcat/conf to /home/praytic/.IntelliJIdea15/system/tomcat/Tomcat_8_0_33_webproject/conf: /opt/tomcat/conf/catalina.properties (Permission denied)
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428126/intellij-needs-to-copy-tomcat-conf-directory-to-project-directory) answer, but it didn't make a thing. I don't know, maybe the reason is that I use wrong installation guide. However it works fine from the terminal. [How To Install Apache Tomcat 8 on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-14-04)

I've checked the `/opt/tomcat/conf` permissions and it says that only root has access to `list, create/delete` the folder and tomcat and me can only list files. However I added myself as a tomcat-user in `tomcat-users.xml`. Doesn't it matter?

Answer (score 0):

The error means that intelliJ needs write access to the conf file. So the other answer was correct. You have to set the write flag with +w or like this:
chmod -R 644 /opt/tomcat/conf/ as root or with sudo.

It has nothing to do with tomcat users, only with OS users. It is unfortunately not enough, that only root has the write permissions, except that IntelliJ would be also started with root permission, but that is also not a good idea.

Comment: As I said, I made all those advises and still no changes.

Comment: But you also wrote that only root has write access. and when you execute the chmod command I wrote then all users will have write access. So you made there something wrong. Did you get an error when you executed it? You will at least need root privilege to do that. So when you are using Ubuntu then you have to execute 

sudo chmod -R 644 /opt/tomcat/conf/

as non root user

Comment: if that is not functional then check also the home folder /home/praytic/.IntelliJIdea15/system/tomcat/Tomcat_8_0_33_webproject/conf

Comment: Ok, I didn't set privileges to myself, but still I feel like this is not right to give me access to the "conf" folder because then tomcat user will have no sense.

Comment: I tried to give myself permissions like you said with `chmod -R 644 /opt/tomcat/conf/` command but it didn't change anything. It still says that I'm not the owner of the "conf" folder and don't have rights to do anything.

Comment: Hi, the chmod permissions are OS permissions. You are right, on a productive system I would not change such permissions, but you are using intelliJ so you I think you are on your development system. when u set the 644 permission then all groups and also all users have read write permissions. when I read your error message, then it sounds for me that IntelliJ has no read permission for the  file /opt/tomcat/conf/catalina.properties It would be nice if you can post the output of   `ls -al /opt/tomcat/conf/`  The tomcat users are only there to manage your Tomcat Container for deploying etc.

Comment: drw-r--r-- 3 root   tomcat   4096 .  
drwxr-xr-x 9 root   root     4096 ..  
drw-r--r-- 3 tomcat tomcat   4096 Catalina  
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   tomcat  12374 catalina.policy  
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   tomcat   7106 catalina.properties  
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   tomcat   1577 context.xml  
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   tomcat   3387 logging.properties  
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   tomcat   6458 server.xml  
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   tomcat   2318 tomcat-users.xml  
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   tomcat   2634 tomcat-users.xsd  
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   tomcat 168822 web.xml