# Intellij won't find Tomcat9's libraries

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, intellij-idea, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to create the very primal `Hello World` program using `Spring` and `Apache Tomcat 9`'s server.
Before all, I want to mentions that I am using `Ubuntu 14.04`

I followed all the steps from [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Zp5suN1b1E&t=300s). (a very basic one).
The problem is at minute [2:35](https://youtu.be/4Zp5suN1b1E?t=2m35s)  when he selects `configure` -> `/opt/tomcat`. If I do the very same, I get this error:

[image]

I've tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16428760/6063416), but still not working ( I can't find the folder in the second part of the answer).
This is my `/apache-tomcat-x/`' folder's permissions:
[image]

Could it be because I followed also [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-14-04), up to the point where I had to

```
sudo initctl start tomcat
```

but because I couldn't access `localhost/8080` I left it like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the following.

1. check the paths again for correctness
2. run `chmod -R 777 /apache-tomcat-x/`
3. restart your IDE once

## Update

The files in your question are owned by the `root` user.
But the IDE is run by your logged in user.
So an even better solution would be to change the owner of the files to your user.

`chown -R alex /apache-tomcat-x/`

Comment: God damn it, it worked!
Can you expand the answer and tell me exactly what file/s should have that right?

Comment: Revisited your question and updated the answer appropriately.