# Unable to start Tomcat in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu, tomcat7

I have installed tomcat using `sudo apt-get install tomcat7` and when i am trying to start the tomcat server using `sudo /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/startup.sh` I am getting the following error

`Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat7/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
touch: cannot touch '/usr/share/tomcat7/logs/catalina.out': No such file or directory
/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/catalina.sh: 389: /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/catalina.sh: cannot create /usr/share/tomcat7/logs/catalina.out: Directory nonexistent`. I went through a similar problem [How to fix 'Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler' error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14428162/tomcat-7-failing-to-start-in-ubuntu-12-04) but the solution says I to re-install tomcat which i don't want to do.Need help

Answer (score 0):

You need to start it as a service, using either `service tomcat start` or `/etc/init.d/tomcat start`.

Comment: But why ? Why i can't start it directly by having in $CATALINA/bin directory and then by executing startup.sh ?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set the `$JAVA_HOME` so that `$JRE_HOME` in tomcat points to the correct Java path.

If you don't hava Java installed, then install the latest version of Java from the Ubuntu software center

Then, in the terminal type

`sudo gedit ~/.bashrc`

This will open the .bashrc file. At the end, add

`export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64`

You should check the exact folder name in `/usr/lib/jvm`

To start tomcat7, in the terminal type

`sudo service tomcat7 start`

And to stop it type

`sudo service tomcat7 stop`

when you type `sudo /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/startup.sh` you should see

`Using JRE_HOME: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64`

Answer (score 0):

I am working through a similar issue setting up tomcat 8 in Ubuntu. Though I am able to manually start using super user script as below, it does not resolve the error I was receiving.

```
sudo service tomcat8 start
```

I can tell you that in my case /usr/share/tomcat7/logs/ folder does not exist.
Take a look at the scripts you are running and check your paths.

I was running the startup.sh and realized that my path was incorrect. I opened the script for startup.sh located in CATALINA_HOME directory. Looked for the failing line: Error: touch: cannot touch '/usr/share/tomcat8/logs/catalina.out'. 
Saw that we were executing the catalina.sh.

```
# Guilty Line in this case
EXECUTABLE=catalina.sh
```

Since the line referenced catalina.sh script, I tried to locate the error in that script. The catalina.sh located in your CATALINA_HOME directory. If you read in the comments these are all default settings.

```
#   CATALINA_OUT    (Optional) Full path to a file where stdout and stderr
#                   will be redirected.
#                   Default is $CATALINA_BASE/logs/catalina.out
```

I found the guilty like and updated the path to match my actual folder path, changed 'logs' to 'log'.

```
if [ -z "$CATALINA_OUT" ] ; then
   CATALINA_OUT="$CATALINA_BASE"/log/catalina.out
fi
```

After I made this update I ran the script again:

```
touch: cannot touch '/usr/share/tomcat8/log/catalina.out': Permission denied
/usr/share/tomcat8/bin/catalina.sh: 402:         
/usr/share/tomcat8/bin/catalina.sh: cannot create     
/usr/share/tomcat8/log/catalina.out: Permission denied
```

This time I had to deal with the permissions for the folders. Make sure that which ever user is calling your script has permissions.